# Xamarin Froms custom template in ListView

Tags: xaml, listview, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm working with the ListView in Xamarin Forms. So far, I've displayed some data using a custom DataTemplate. Now, I would like to extend this to display the text inside/ over an image. Something like this:

[image]

This is the code, I'm using so far. However, in this case the text is over the image:

```
<ListView x:Name="MyListView"
          ItemsSource="{Binding myData}"
          RowHeight="190"
          HasUnevenRows="True">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
          <ViewCell.View>
            <StackLayout Padding="10" Orientation="Vertical">
              <Label Text="{Binding Title}" 
                     FontSize="Large" 
                     VerticalOptions="Center"
                     TextColor="#31659e">
               </Label>                
               <Image Source="http://www.someurl.com/images/image1.jpg" Aspect="AspectFill"></Image>                  
            </StackLayout>
          </ViewCell.View>
        </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
```

How could I achieve the result of the first image?

If anyone has some example/ links/ tips how to do that, that would be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: You can bind a bool property to IsVisable property,disable other items

Comment: Have a look at this [snppt](https://snppts.io/snippet/23) we're trying to create a platform with these kind of designs. This has some text over background image that you're after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `RelativeLayout`. It would look like this in your data templates `ViewCell.View`

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <!-- Background -->
    <Image Source="http://www.someurl.com/images/image1.jpg" Aspect="AspectFill"
           RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}"
           RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height}" />
    <!-- Text -->
    <StackLayout Padding="10" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                 RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}"
                 RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height}" >
      <Label Text="{Binding Title}"
             FontSize="Large"
             TextColor="#31659e">
      </Label>
      <Label Text="{Binding SubTitle}"
             TextColor="#31659e">
      </Label>
    </StackLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This stretches the image and the stacklayout to the same height and aligns the content of the `StackLayout` at the botttom.

Comment: That code works as expected. I only did a few tweaks, Thanks

Comment: Now the data is displaying as the image above. Only the text is been displaying at the top instead of the bottom. I'm working on that. But in general, the code works.